# What would be the best way to use iCloud to upload photos to Facebook/Google+?

Tags: data-synchronization, photos, facebook, google, icloud

I'd like to use iCloud in a manner similar to what Android users get with Google+. I'd like to take a picture with my iPhone, and have it automatically uploaded to (and thus permanently stored on) either Facebook or Google+ without having to do anything about it.

At present, it seems to me that the way to do this would be to sync my iPhone and a server with iCloud, and have some service (one that I'll write if I have to or one that is hopefully available or planned) running on the server that monitors the photo directory for new photos, and then uploads them via a Facebook or Google API.

Does this sound like the simplest way to get the sort of snap and forget photo functionality that I desire?

Comment: iCloud does not have any features that connect it to Facebook and Google+. From the sounds of it, any answer to this question would be speculative at best. Will Apple decide to add such a feature to iCloud? I highly doubt it, but my point is that this type of question cannot be answered as a fact. You mention that perhaps you can write such a service? If so, then this question belongs in StackOverflow--assuming it is reworded as a question that says something along the lines of "How can I create a service that will sync an iCloud Photo Stream with Google+ or Facebook?".

Answer (score 2):

That won't be possible. iCloud is not a sharing/hosting service (at least concerning photos). It is a syncing service. And photos aren't stored for more than 30 days.

And only Apple devices can connect to the iCloud service/servers. There is no general API.

To get what you want, you'd have to write an app that does this and miss out iCloud completely.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a free service specifically for this kind of thing, it's called If This Then That (ifttt.com). You can configure all different types of cloud and other services with it, and then use pre-configured "recipes" or create our own. You can create all kinds of cool automated actions with it that will save you lots of time. I personally have it back up all my iOS photos to Dropbox and also copy them to my Flickr page but you can easily set it up to post to a Facebook album instead (I use it the other way, I have it copy any photos I'm tagged in to my iCloud photos). I also have it copy a link to my FB posts to my Twitter feed, and use it with my Amazon Echo to turn on lights, etc.